# Azure DevOps: add a user to a Project but not to the Organization

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to add a User to a specific Project without adding her/him to the Organization?

I need to add an external developer to the project but I'd like to limit as much as possible her/his visibility on other organization members and projects.

Comment: No its not possible. User should belong to the organization in order to have access in the project as every project is part of the organization. Nonetheless if the user is only added to one project, then it should have visibility only to this particular project. You can go under `Users->Group rules-> Add group rule-> Select on which project user should be added`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a User to a specific Project without adding her/him to the Organization?

Agree with GeralexGR. I am afraid that there is no method to add a user to a Project but not to the Organization.

When a user is added to a project, the user will be added to the organization as a member of the organization.

Based on your requirement, you want to limit as much as possible her/his visibility on other organization members and projects.

I suggest that you can add the user to **Project-Scoped Users Group** in **Organization Settings -> Permissions**.

Here is the doc: [Limit user visibility for projects and more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/manage-organization-collection?view=azure-devops#limit-user-visibility-for-projects-and-more)

Then the user will have no access to see the members at Organization level.

At the same time, you can grant user the access to target project in **Organization Settings -> Users -> Target User -> Manager User** .

Comment: We have several users that are found only in the project but not the organization.

Is it possible that they were added directly to a projects' group but those users never logged into the project/org?